# Cartesian State Vectors → Keplerian Orbit Elements

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

So, I've been working my way through the following as I'm messing about with programming some helper functions for orbital mechanics: https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf

Given I don't have the greatest understanding of mathematical notation I've run into a spot of bother understanding what $||r||$ in the following formula means:

$\frac{r}{||r||}$

Keep in mind that r is a vector from element 1.b

Comment: Here, the length of a vector $r$ is written $\Vert r\Vert$, so that you’re dividing a vector by its (scalar) length, to get a unit vector in the same direction. It’s a common way of getting the direction of a vector, throwing away its magnitude.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work, if you are still around, I've gotten a bit further and would you know what they are trying to tell me with: n = (0, 0, 1)T × h = (−hy, hx, 0)T

Comment: I am around, but what kind of mathematical object is $T$ in this case? I can’t think of an interpretation of it that makes the expression grammatical.

Comment: Ah, I messed up, this is better. $n = (0, 0, 1)^T × h = (−h_y, h_x, 0)^T$ n and h are vectors, they don't seem to explain what T is doing. Also, I think that $⟨e,r⟩$ is the delta of those two vectors?

Comment: Still not enough information. Maybe the $T$ is for transpose, turning a row vector into a column vector? This is definitely not my meat, but please don’t hesitate to e-mail me.

Comment: Yeah, got some help from other guys, the T indicates a transpose. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to put in a comment, so I am giving it as an answer, though Lubin already answered your actual question and this is in response to your comments.

Your vectors are column vectors, so technically, they should be written as $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \times h = \begin{bmatrix} -h_y \\ h_x \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

But they wanted to write it on just one line, so they used the transpose operator $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{and}\qquad\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

to represent the column vector as row vectors instead.

The operation "$\times$" here is the vector *cross-product*. It is defined by:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} bz - cy \\ cx - az \\ ay - bx\end{bmatrix}$$

You can check yourself that if $h = \begin{bmatrix} h_x & h_y & h_z\end{bmatrix}^T$, then the cross-product really is as given.

An important fact about the cross-product is that it is orthogonal to (i.e. makes a right angle with) both of the multiplicands. That is, $n$ will be perpendicular to both $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and to $h$, which is doubtless why they are making use of it here. They want something perpendicular to both directions.

$\langle e, r\rangle$ is the *inner product*, or *dot product* of the two vectors $e$ and $r$. The second name is because it is also common to represent it as $e \cdot r$ instead of $\langle e, r\rangle$. It is defined by
$$\langle e, r\rangle = e^Tr = e_xr_x + e_yr_y + e_zr_z$$
Note that unlike the cross-product, the inner product is a number, not a vector.

The inner product has two uses that are particularly important:

- for any vector $v$, it's length (or magnitude) is $\|v\| := \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}$.
- Two vectors $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal (i.e. perpendicular) if and only if $\langle v, w\rangle = 0$.

In particular, for your vectors above, $\langle n, h\rangle =0$ and $\langle n, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T\rangle = 0$, as you can easily verify by plugging into the formulas.